# Fisher information of independent observations with transformation of parameters

Tags: estimation, fisher-information

Let $\boldsymbol\theta$ be a vector parameter, which can be estimated from two different time observation models (stochastic processes) $\mathbf{y}_1(t)$ and  $\mathbf{y}_2(t)$. The Fisher information matrices (FIMs) are obtained via these two models and denoted by $\mathbf{J}_1^{\boldsymbol\theta}$ and $\mathbf{J}_2^{\boldsymbol\theta}$, respectively.

Assuming that the two observations are independent, then the total Fisher information available is the sum of both matrices, that is
\begin{align}
\mathbf{J}^{\boldsymbol\theta}=\mathbf{J}_1^{\boldsymbol\theta}+\mathbf{J}_2^{\boldsymbol\theta}
\end{align}

In fact, we are interested in another parameter, say $\boldsymbol\phi\triangleq\mathbf{g}_k(\boldsymbol\theta)$, where $\mathbf{g}_k(\cdot), k=1,2,$ is a vector function mapping $\boldsymbol\theta$ with $\boldsymbol\phi$ in the $k^{th}$ observation model.

My question, what is the total FIM of $\boldsymbol\phi$, that is $\mathbf{J}^{\boldsymbol\phi}$.

$\textbf{Attempts}$:
It is well-established that when we have just one observation model, then
\begin{align}
\mathbf{J}_1^{\boldsymbol\phi}=\mathbf{T}_1\mathbf{J}_1^{\boldsymbol\theta}\mathbf{T}_1^\mathrm{T},
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{T}_1\triangleq\frac{\partial\boldsymbol\theta}{\partial\boldsymbol\phi}$, is obtained from $\boldsymbol\phi=\mathbf{g}_1(\boldsymbol\theta)$

Can we just say that 
\begin{align}
\mathbf{J}^{\boldsymbol\phi}&=\mathbf{J}_1^{\boldsymbol\phi}+\mathbf{J}_2^{\boldsymbol\phi},\\
&=\mathbf{T}_1\mathbf{J}_1^{\boldsymbol\theta}\mathbf{T}_1^\mathrm{T}+\mathbf{T}_2\mathbf{J}_2^{\boldsymbol\theta}\mathbf{T}_2^\mathrm{T}.
\end{align}

If this is not possible, and we need to transform the parameters after the addition, what $\mathbf{T}$ should we use?
\begin{align}
\mathbf{J}^{\boldsymbol\phi}&=\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{J}_1^{\boldsymbol\theta}+\mathbf{J}_2^{\boldsymbol\theta})\mathbf{T}^\mathrm{T}
\end{align}